# How to iterate only the ChildNodes that match certain Name (XmlDocument)

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following nested loops

```
foreach (XmlNode nodeT in root.ChildNodes)
{
    foreach (XmlNode nodeServicio in nodeT.ChildNodes)
    {
        nombreMayusculas = nodeServicio.Name.ToUpper();

        if (nombreMayusculas.Contains("SERVICE"))
        {
            int a = 0;
            int.TryParse(nombreMayusculas.Replace("SERVICE", ""), out a);

            if (a.Equals(Type))
            {
                  //some logic here to process only the matching Xmlnode
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Is there a way to loop only the matching XmlNodes that match both conditions ?

**I have tried using the `Where` linq method but is not available and I already have the `using System.Linq`**

Here is the XML

```
<Clients>
    <AgoraCOR1 Type=\"SP\" Default=\"False\">
        <Connectionstring>CONN_STRING</Connectionstring>
        <Service002>SaveOperationNotification</Service002>
        <Service106>SaveOrderNotification</Service106>
    </AgoraCOR1>
    <SerficorpOrdenes1 Type=\"SP\" Default=\"False\">
        <Connectionstring>CONN_STRING</Connectionstring>
        <Service106>SaveOrderNotification</Service106>
        <Service017>SaveComplementationNotification</Service017>
    </SerficorpOrdenes1>
    <CorrevalCORInterno1 Type=\"SP\" Default=\"False\">
        <Connectionstring>CONN_STRING</Connectionstring>
        <Service002>SaveOperationNotification</Service002>
        <Service074>SaveIndicatorNotification</Service074>
        <Service106>SaveOrderNotification</Service106>
        <Service017>SaveComplementationNotification</Service017>
        <Service072>SalvarNotificacionPreciosDeMercado</Service072>
    </CorrevalCORInterno1>
</Clients>
```

Comment: use `nodeT.SelectNodes(...)` method.

Comment: If you're able to use LINQ to XML, all of this becomes simpler. (It's a much nicer XML API in general.)

Comment: Can you show example of xml you are working with? We will be able to suggest best approach to parse it

Comment: @MauricioGracia can you add this info to question? Also what sevice nodes look like?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I have included the relevant part of the XML

Comment: @JonSkeet can you please post an answer that shows me what you mean

Comment: @MauricioGracia ok, updated regex according to your xml. Works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not completely clear how your xml looks like, but I suppose you have service nodes with names like *service1*, *service2*, etc. You can use regular expression to test if node name matches service type (you can change pattern if xml structure differs):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
Regex regex = new Regex(String.Format("^Service{0}$", Type));
var services = from s in xdoc.Root.Elements().Elements()                   
               where regex.IsMatch(s.Name.LocalName)
               select s;
```

---

Alternative solution with XPath (you should add System.Xml.XPath) namespace:

```
var xpath = String.Format("Clients/*/*[name() = 'Service{0}']", Type);
var services = xdoc.XPathSelectElements(xpath);
```

Same solution with old XmlDocument class:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path_to_xml);

foreach(XmlNode nodeServicio in doc.SelectNodes(xpath)) // xpath same as above
   // use nodeServicio
```

Comment: have you read that also, for some reason the WHERE method is not being recognized ?

Comment: @MauricioGracia looks like you are trying to use XmlDocument instead of XDocument. XmlNode does not implement generic `IEnumerable<T>` interface. Thus `Where` extension is not available for you

Comment: thanks for your help, this XML document is used in many other places and I will have to migrate that code from XmlDocument to XDocument

Comment: @MauricioGracia I also added alternative solution which also works with your current code. But I suggest you to move to Linq to Xml - it's easier to use then old XmlDocument API

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq - but it will have the same performance profile, to what you have already done:

```
var nodesToProcess = root
    .ChildNodes
    .ChildNodes
    .Where(n => n.Name.ToUpper().Contains("SERVICE")));

foreach(var node in nodesToProcess)
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second loop can be rewritten as below.

```
var result = from nodeServicio in nodeT.ChildNodes
             where nodeServicio.Name.ToUpper().Contains("SERVICE")
             select nodeServicio;//or something else
```

EDIT:

From the code you posted.. I'm guessing that the child nodes would have values which look like SERVICE123, 12SERVICE etc

```
int type = 5; //integer
if (nombreMayusculas.Contains("SERVICE"))
{
    int a = 0;
    int.TryParse(nombreMayusculas.Replace("SERVICE", ""), out a);

    //You cannot use Equals here.. used only for string comparison
    if (a == type))
    {
        //some logic here to process only the matching Xmlnode
    }
}
```

Comment: Krishna I have edited my post, could you please update your answer

Comment: @MauricioGracia - i've updated my answer. For some reason, if you're unable to use LINQ, then don't use it.. im not sure if there is a performance increase for your case for linq vs non-linq